# Angular ng-controller with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I don't understand well how ng-controller works with Angular:

I have my **documentSearch.component.html:** (That's only the part linked to the controller)

```
<div ng-controller=mainCtrl>
      <div mass-autocomplete>
        <input ng-model="dirty.value"
               mass-autocomplete-item="autocomplete_options">
      </div>
</div>
```

And the **documentSearch.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-documentsearch',
  templateUrl: './document-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./document-search.component.css']
})

export class DocumentSearchComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {...}

    ngOnInit(){...}

    someFunction(...){...}

}
```

And the code i want to try is this one:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'MassAutoComplete']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $q) {
$scope.dirty = {};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'California', /* ... */ ];

function suggest_state(term) {
var q = term.toLowerCase().trim();
var results = [];

// Find first 10 states that start with `term`.
for (var i = 0; i < states.length && results.length < 10; i++) {
  var state = states[i];
  if (state.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) === 0)
    results.push({ label: state, value: state });
}

return results;
}

 $scope.autocomplete_options = {
   suggest: suggest_state
 };
});
```

But I don't understand how to use it. Do I have to use it on my `documentSearch.component.ts`, do I have to create an other class for the controller ?

What do I have to change on this code for Typescript ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are mixing up [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (Angular 1.x) and [Angular](https://angular.io/) (Angular 2-6) code.

The **documentSearch.component.ts** file is modern Angular, but **documentSearch.component.html** is an AngularJS template. The code you want to try out also is AngularJS.

While both frameworks were developed by the same team, they are utterly different on many levels. For example Angular focuses on components, while in AngularJS controllers are (usually) separated from templates. Also the template syntax is entirely different, and while Angular is based on TypeScript itself, AngularJS only has mediocre TypeScript support overall.

To summarize: Pick one framework and stick with it. You cannot easily integrate AngularJS code in Angular applications or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to learn angular, but you don't know it's history.
Refer to [Angular Tutorial](http://www.angular.io). You will not find ng-controller there. Because it is part of AngularJS, that was first in the line of angular production. Angular 2 was rewritten, not just upgraded from AngularJS. So, Angular 2 and above doesn't follow those syntaxes.